# What does this Java expression mean?

Tags: java, operators

I am pressed for time and thought will post my query here. I'm new to Java and this should be very elementary but I could not get any answer from Google.

What does the second line below mean?

```
double mutatePercent = 0.01;
boolean m1 = rand.nextFloat() <= mutatePercent;
```

I thought <= meant less than or equal to, but that doesn't seem so in the above usage. How is m1's value decided?

Thanks!

Comment: Yes, it is less than or equal to. It assign the comparison result (which is boolean type) to m1.

Answer (score 4):

The line

```
boolean m1 = rand.nextFloat() <= mutatePercent;
```

is of the form

```
boolean m1 = <some boolean value>
```

and

```
rand.nextFloat() <= mutatePercent;
```

results in a boolean value, so the result of the comparison `rand.nextFloat() <= mutatePercent` is assigned to the `boolean` variable `m1`

Answer (score 0):

> I thought <= meant less than or equal to

It does.

> but that doesn't seem so in the above usage.

Why not?

---

```
boolean m1 = rand.nextFloat() <= mutatePercent;
```

Assigns the value of the condition *"Is this random float less than or equal to `0.01`?"* to the variable `m1`. So, `m1` is true iff the randomly generated number is less than or equal to `0.01`.

Answer (score 0):

That's exactly what it means.  The second line performs the "less-than-or-equal" test and assigns the result - ie. true or false - to the boolean variable `m1`.